# Which is the most efficient operation to split an integer to two characters in an Arduino?

Tags: arduino

Which of the following two approches is more efficient on an [ATmega328P](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega328p.aspx)?

```
unsigned int value;
unsigned char char_high, char_low;

char_high = value>>8;
value = value<<8;
char_low = value>>8;
```

OR

```
unsigned int value;
unsigned char char_high, char_low;

char_high = value>>8;
char_low = value & 0xff;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should measure.  I won't answer your question (since you'd benefit more from measuring than I would), but I'll give you a third option:

```
struct {
    union {
        uint16_t big;
        uint8_t small[2];
    };
} nums;
```

(be aware of the difference between big endian and little endian here)

Comment: How can I measure? I am little weak in programing.

Comment: You try however many different ways you can think of, then you measure how much time each one takes.

On an Arduino, in your "loop()" function, you have a for() loop that calls your test code some number of times.  Before the for() loop save the return value from micros(), and subtract it from the value of micros() afterwards.  Output the difference on the serial port and view the times with the serial monitor (I assume you're using the IDE).

BTW -- the union should work best, so long as you know which endian the ATmega chips are, which you can learn on your own.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to measure it (as has already been said).

Or, compile both and see what the assembly language output looks like.

but actually, the 2nd code you have won't work - if you take  `value << 8` and assign it to a `char`, all you get is zero in the `char`.  The subsequent `>>8` will still leave you with zero.